# Help in a rectilinear motion problem in calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A particle moves along the $x$-axis according to the equation

$$s(t) = \frac 13 t^3 -t^2 -8t +12$$

where $s$ is the directed distance (in meters) of the particle from the origin at time $t$ (in seconds). Find:

1. the directed distance of the particle from the origin, its
   velocity and acceleration at the following time instants: $t = 0, 1, 
   2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. Describe the particle’s motion at these time
   instants.
2. the time instant/s when the particle is instantaneously at rest.
3. the time instant/s when the particle is in uniform motion.
4. the time interval/s when the particle is  moving to the right/left.
5. the time interval/s when the particle is accelerating/decelerating.
6. The trace of the particle’s motion on the $x$-axis

Hello, I'm having a hard time setting up and solving this problem. any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to look at the function and it's derivatives.

1) Overall placement of the particle is just defined as s(t) - that is exactly how you defined it. The instantaneous change in direction (speed) is represented as s'(t) and the change in the change in direction (the rate of change of speed, the acceleration) is s"(t). Plug in t accordingly.

2) Instantaneously at rest suggests that the motion of the particle is unchanging, meaning find all points where s'(t) = 0.

3) Uniform motion implies s"(t) = 0.

4) This is asking about it's motion, specifically the direction of motion. This is represented as the sign of s'(t). So where s'(t) > 0, its's moving to the right, and where s'(t) < 0, it's moving to the left.

5) Similar to number 4, the acceleration and deceleration refer to the sign of s"(t). Match up the inequalities appropriately.

6) At any given t, your particle is at s(t) place. To draw that into a function (and therefore giving you the "trace" of its motion), change the variable to x and set the equation equal to y. You now have a graph of the particle's motion.